# React. Тип event-а для получения closest dataset-а

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть функция, обработчик клика по элементу:

```
function toggleSelect(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const id = e.target?.closest('[data-id]')?.dataset?.id
    
  if (id) {
    selected === id 
      ? setSelected(null) 
      : setSelected(id)
  }
}
```

Но `typescript` ругается на `closest`:
**TS2339: Property 'closest' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'**

---

Если поменять немного код:

```
const id = (e.target as Element)?.closest('[data-id]')?.dataset?.id
```

`typescript` ругается на `dataset`
**TS2339: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'Element'**

---

Какой тип нужно присвоить `event`-у, чтобы не было ошибок?
(кроме `any` конечно)

Comment: Ну используйте `HTMLElement` вместо `Element` в чём проблема?

Comment: @EzioMercer Ошибка та же как и с Element

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в том что `closest` возвращает тип `Element`, потому у него и нет `dataset`.

Вам вместо:

```
(e.target as Element)?.closest('[data-id]')?.dataset?.id
```

надо написать:

```
((e.target as Element)?.closest('[data-id]') as HTMLElement)?.dataset?.id
```

Comment: Работает. А есть возможность это вынести в тип аргумента?

```function someFunc(e: SomeType)```

Comment: @HaZcker Вряд ли ведь дело в самом методе `closest` и он возвращает только тип `Element`. Так что нужно будет в какой-то момент написать `as HTMLElement`

Answer (score 0):

Тип для аргумента так и не нашёл, но решил задачу по ответу @EzioMercer написав хелпер

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'

function getTargetDataValue(
  e: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
  key: string
): string | undefined {
  const selector = `[data-${key}]`
  return ((e.target as Element)?.closest(selector) as HTMLElement)?.dataset[key]
}

export { getTargetDataValue }
```

---

Теперь код обработчика выглядит так:

```
function toggleSelect(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
  const id = getTargetDataValue(e, 'id')
    
  if (id) {
    selected === id 
      ? setSelected(null) 
      : setSelected(id)
  }
}
```